# Is there an advantage to using nested namespaces instead of Partial Public NotInheritable Classes

Tags: vb.net, class, namespaces, shared

It seems advantages of using `Partial` `NotInheritable` `Class` is that one can declare/implement shared methods in them.

Here is a code sample, to help visualize the matter.

```
Namespace MyNamespace.Utility
    ' Cannot Declare Shared Function
    Public NotInheritable Class Document
        ' Can Declare Shared Function        
    End Class
End Namespace
```

This is opposed to

```
Namespace MyNamespace
    Partial Public NotInheritable Class Utility
        ' Can Declare Shared Function
        Partial Public NotInheritable Class Document
            ' Can Declare Shared Function
        End Class
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Note 'Collection' is an imported namespace from another Component. It's a collection of the KeyValuePairs of TypeDef Classes/Object (Data Types) I have defined throughout my project.

Comment: looking at this old question, it should probably be moved to a different SO community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utility should be a namespace because it is acting as a logical grouping. 
[Microsoft .NET Framework Nested Types Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229027%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

I don't follow your claim that an advantage of a sealed class is that you can define static methods, any class can do that.

Comment: Right, but the comparison was a sealed class to a namespace.

The article you referenced

Comment: pardon the cut off..

The article you referenced doesn't seem to fit properly with the concept of sealed classes vs namespaces.. as the declaration of variables and instances of objects don't apply.

Nested objects are Logical groupings as well. There is no practical difference in their usage, right? MyComponent.Utility.Document.GetLatestReportCollection() is accessible whether or not Utility is a class or namespace.

Comment: perhaps the better question is, is there a benefit to using nested namespaces, rather than Using NotInheritable classes composed of Public Shared methods.

Comment: With nested types you MUST declare the containing type to access it. That is your code would always be Utility.Document.GetLatestReportCollection(). Using a namespace you can cut it down to Document.GetLatestReportCollection(). Granted intellisense can cut down on the code that's written but it seems like extra noise to me. I'm still not clear on why you are drawing a comparison between a sealed class and namespaces, your second example is clearly a nested type that just so happens to use sealed classes.